# Find pair of numbers in 2 dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, search, multidimensional-array

what is the fast way to 
 find pair of numbers in 2 dimention array

i have this array

```
 int[,] numbers = new int[,] { { 5, 2 }, { 5, 1 }, { 5, 0 } , ........... };
```

i have to integers like `x,y`

i want to return the index of this pair apper in the array

if the pair dont exist retun false

thanks

Comment: need more details to decide 'fast'.  Is the array ordered?  If not, you are looking at a linear search.

Comment: its not ordered, is there  a build in function to do it ?

Comment: Sounds a little like homework.

Comment: no home work i build an little application to client

Comment: there is not as far as I know.  A general solution is rough.  for example, int[][,,][,] numbers; is a legal declaration of an array in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is not ordered, the best you can do is a linear search - either row by row, column by column, or even by diagonal.

If either of the dimensions of the array are ordered, then you could use binary search.

If the data is ordered and also conforms to some kind of distribution, you could use a distribution correlation lookup, which could be slightly more efficient than binary search.

Comment: by rows is faster, because it will produce less cache misses :)

Answer (score 1):

If the array is ordered you can use a binary search.
Otherwise you will have to do a linear search.

Comment: or sort it and do binary search :)

Comment: @Andrey: Sorting the data only helps if lookups will be performed frequently. Otherwise, the cost of sorting outweighs the benefits of the improvements offered by binary search.

Comment: @LBushkin, that depends on your definition of "frequently".  Quicksort is O(n log n) on average, and binary search is O(log n)  if N is large, and is not a pathological case for the Quicksort, then sorting it will help in cases where you are searching for as few as two items.

Comment: @John Gietzen: True. I was trying to point out that performing a sort operation prior to each search would reduce performance. Sorting and re-using the sorted array for more than one search may indeed pay for itself rather quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Do the sorting of 2D array and then use Binary search.

Comment: Using Array.Sort() uses a QuickSort algorithm, making the best case nlogn time and introducing the possibility of a pathological scenario for QuickSort (n^2 time). You could scan an unordered list in linear time. Your answer IS better if searching for multiple values on a list that doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

"Fastest" is vague; fastest to write, or fastest to execute?

The fastest you could get this on an unordered list would be linear, and the actual best and worst cases would depend on the input data. The fastest overall on an unordered list would probably be:

```
var i = 0;
foreach(var subarray in numbers)
{
   if(subarray[0] == x && subarray[1] == y || subarray[0] == y && subarray[1] == x)
     return i;
   i++;
}
```

Best case is that the first element has the elements in order; 1 element, 2 equality comparisons. Worst case is it's not there; n elements, n*4 equality comparisons.

You can "fail fast" in situations where it is unlikely that a match will be found, by checking to see if the subarray has at least one element with at least one of the coordinates. If not, don't bother checking for an exact match. That makes the worst case that the element is the last one, out of order (n*2 elements, n*6 comparisons), but the best case is that it isn't there (n elements, n*2 comparisons, which if this case is likely is better than the previous).

Lastly, the "fail fast" algorithm allows for using Linq to narrow the number of elements on which you make the full set of conditional checks; you first look for elements that have at least one of the coordinates (requiring a max of two checks), then check only those for elements that match exactly (a max of four checks). Then, you scan the array for the first element you found, which is a relatively fast referential check.

```
var result = numbers.Where(a=>a[0] == x || a[0] == y)
   .Where(a=>a[0] == x && a[1] == y || a[0] == y && a[1] == x)
   .FirstOrDefault();

if(result != null) return Array.IndexOf(numbers, result);
```

Best case, it's not there (n elements, n*2 comparisons). Only slightly worse is the probably-likely case that only one element has either of the coordinates (n+1 elements, n*2+(2 or 4) comparisons). Worst case, the match is the last element, out of order, AND every element in the list has a first coordinate that is x or y (n*3 elements, n*7 comparisons, but this is EXTREMELY unlikely in most real data). The average case will depend on the number of elements that have at least one of the coordinates as its first value.